# 2D Scrolling Background on XNA

Tags: xna, 2d

How do I create a scrolling X and scrolling Y background without weird things happening like the player disappearing or not getting the offset correct?

I have code at https://vanillity.kilnhg.com/Code/Repositories/Group/Aremac

Looks like this:

```
      var s = game.gd.Viewport.Bounds;
      var g = game.world.Bounds;
      var p = game.player.Bounds;
      var v = viewRectangle;

      var x = p.X  0 ? p.X - s.Width/2 :
              v.Right >= 1090 ?  90 :
              p.X > s.Width/2    ? p.X - s.Width/2 :
              0;


      var y = //v.Bottom > 
              p.Y > s.Height/2 ? p.Y - s.Height/2:
              0;

      var w = s.Width;
      var h = s.Height;

      //view Rectangle
      Offset        = new Vector2(x , y);
      viewRectangle = new Rectangle( x, y ,w, h);
```

and then:

```
     //source rectangle
     var x = (int)0;
     var y = (int)0;
     var g = game.world.Bounds;
     var w = g.Width;
     var h = g.Height;
     var rect =  new Rectangle(x,y,w,h);


      spriteBatch.Draw(  w.boundsTexture 
                        ,rect
                        ,viewRectangle                                 
                        ,w.Color
                        ,0
                        ,Vector2.Zero
                        ,SpriteEffects.None
                        ,1
                        );
```

Before center, the grey guy is holding the rock in his left hand:
[image: Before X]

After center, the rock (and the white guy) drifts evermore to the right:
[image: After X]

Comment: It would help if you provided screen shots of the problems occurring, and under what circumstances they occur. IE if your character disappears only when moving up or the background image jumps when it loops. Things like that will help locate problematic code.

Comment: It gets wonky when I pass to the right of world.Center.X
Feel free to check out the code and run it.

Comment: I also added images.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite this statement in a more readable fashion:

```
var x = p.X > v.Width     ? p.X - v.X/2: 
          p.X > s.Width/2   ? p.X - s.Width/2 :
          0;
```

And your problem is solved.

```
if p.X > v.Width then
    x = p.x - v.x/2;
else
    if p.x > s.width/2 then
        x = p.x - s.width/2;
    else 
        x=0;
```

Also, your viewRect should never have it's width or height changing. You seem to be trying to over complicate things.

You need a viewport offset for X and Y.
You need a player position.
The viewport offset is p.offset - viewport.size / 2
The viewport has a size.

You then want to draw from viewport offset (maybe - 1) to viewport offset + viewport size.

Comment: I didn't change the viewRect w * h. I just preferred using the `h` and `w` variables.

Comment: It doesnt seem like your solution worked.

Comment: And I just updated my code to a klugey fix.